# Rational approximation or series expansion of $K_0$ and $K_1$ for small z

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, approximation

I'm looking for a series expansion of the modified Bessel functions of second kind $K_0(z)$ and $K_1(z)$ for
$$|z|<5, ~~|phase(z)| < \pi$$
My $z$ can be described as $z = a\cdot \sqrt{ix}$, where $x$ is real. The task is quite troublesome as the usual approach $$K_v(z)=\frac{\pi}{2\sin(v\pi)}[I_{-v}(z)-I_{v}(z)]$$ 
is not valid for integer order functions. If one calculates the limit of this equation one gets a certainly valid result, which can be found in literature. But it is rather bulky and it contains terms with $\log(0.5\cdot z)$ which is not applicable for my case. I require a rational approximation.

There is an article [*On the numerical evaluation of the modified bessel function of the third kind*](http://wwwdb.dbod.de:2070/science/article/pii/0021999175900820) which suggests $$K_v(z) = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{z}{2})^{-v}\Gamma(v) ~~~for~~ v>0$$
which is alright for $K_1$ and |z|<3. But it's not sufficient. Do you have any ideas or sources what else to try to expand the range to |z|<5 and also for $K_0$?

Edit: I also found the article [*Rational approximations for the modified Bessel function of the second kind*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/001046559090089J) which seemed to offer a good solution. But I implemented it in Matlab and got a quite weird behavior, I assume caused by overflow.

Comment: Do you have Mathematica available?  You might be able to get a usable rational approximation using interpolation.

Comment: $K_0$ has the integral representation $$\int_1^{\infty} e^{-zt}/\sqrt{t^2-1}$$ which can be approximated by quadrature when $Re(z) > 0$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I made bad experiences with interpolation for these kind of problems, as I would need to interpolate again and again for different $a$. I need a valid model for various $a$.

Comment: @user7530 could you specify what you mean, maybe in an answer?